# Ubuntu 20.04 Bluetooth Broken

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth

I paired some headphones via Bluetoot the other day and it has been working correctly for a while.

Today, when I booted the laptop (which has 20.04), Blueman wouldn't start anymore.

On a cold start, Blueman throws the following error.

```
Bluez daemon is not running, blueman-manager cannot continue.
This probabil means that there were no Bluetooth adapters detected or Bluetooth daemon was not started.
```

The output of *dmesg | grep -i blue*

```
[    5.926932] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluez, revision 266...
```

The output of *lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb* is:

```
Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter   [168c:0042] (rev 31)
Subsystem: Dell QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:1810]
Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

At this point the result of *rfkill list* is

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

The result of *systemctl | grep -i blue*

```
run-snapd-ns-bluez.mnt.mount                                                           loaded active     mounted   /run/snapd/ns/bluez.mnt                                                      
snap-bluez-266.mount                                                                   loaded active     mounted   Mount unit for bluez, revision 266                                           
● snap.bluez.bluez.service                                                               loaded failed     failed    Service for snap application bluez.bluez                                     
● snap.bluez.obex.service                                                                loaded failed     failed    Service for snap application bluez.obex
```

The result of *systemctl status snap.bluez.bluez.service* is:

```
snap.bluez.bluez.service - Service for snap application bluez.bluez
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap.bluez.bluez.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-12-17 18:35:38 EET; 5min ago
Process: 1337 ExecStart=/usr/bin/snap run bluez (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 1337 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

The status of the bluetooth service at this point is:

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: inactive (dead)
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Dec 17 18:35:37 Roxy systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

The output of *lsbusb* is:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:5520 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

After this if I load the module with *modprobe btusb* and start the service, the bluetooth service will be shown with green

```
bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-12-17 18:44:47 EET; 2s ago
   Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
Main PID: 3893 (bluetoothd)
 Status: "Running"
  Tasks: 1 (limit: 9168)
 Memory: 1.9M
 CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
         └─3893 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Dec 17 18:44:47 Roxy systemd[1]: Starting Bluetooth service...
Dec 17 18:44:47 Roxy bluetoothd[3893]: Bluetooth daemon 5.53
Dec 17 18:44:47 Roxy systemd[1]: Started Bluetooth service.
Dec 17 18:44:47 Roxy bluetoothd[3893]: Starting SDP server
Dec 17 18:44:47 Roxy bluetoothd[3893]: Bluetooth management interface 1.14 initialized
```

This time the output *dmesg | grep -i blue* is

```
[    6.603768] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluez, revision 266... [20988.422158] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22 [20988.422180] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized [20988.422182] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized [20988.422184] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized [20988.422186] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized [20988.467613] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3 [20988.467614] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast [20988.467618] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

At this point when I try to start Blueman again, I get the following:

```
blueman-manager 18.45.16 ERROR    Manager:118 on_dbus_name_appeared: Default adapter not found, trying first available.
blueman-manager 18.45.16 ERROR    Manager:122 on_dbus_name_appeared: No adapter(s) found, exiting
```

As you can see I tried quite a few things, I spent an hour trying to diagnose the problem, but the issue is starting to be at a lower level than I'm comfortable with.

I'd really like to stay with Ubuntu on this machine, so please help me out.

Thanks!

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue` to your question.

Comment: @Pilot6 Before loading the module 
`[    5.926932] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluez, revision 266...`

Comment: @Pilot6

After the modprobe command it is:

`[    6.603768] systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for bluez, revision 266...
[20988.422158] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[20988.422180] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[20988.422182] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[20988.422184] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[20988.422186] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[20988.467613] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[20988.467614] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[20988.467618] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized`

Comment: Add information to the question.

Comment: @Pilot6 done, I added the info to the question. Do you have some info regarding the question?

Comment: You didn't add it to the question. Please add the full output.

Comment: @Pilot6 I did, check again, I put the outputs before and after modprobe command, please read it again

Do you have any ideas about the actual issue?